# Background custom camera view with blur effect in Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, view, camera

I want to make a launch screen for an app that has got a custom camera view in the background which is blurred by a visual effect view. In the foreground you've got all the important buttons for the login.

My custom camera view is already finished and works fine; the problem is, that I can't add any buttons or a blur effect to it, and I don't know why. Here's my storyboard scene:

[image: My storyboard]

I was expecting it looking like that: blurred camera view in the background, login button in the foreground.

Instead, it looks like this:

[image: What the actual app looks like]

Can anyone explain me why that happens and what I have to do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your hierarchy. It should be like this:
View

```
 - Camera View
 - Visual Effect View
     - View
         - Login (Button)
```

And try rearranging your views because there is a bug that seems to reorder the elements without showing you.

Comment: I tried that, but apparently I can't have several views on the same "layer" if you know what I mean... When I try to rearrange them to the same position, it gives me an error :(

Comment: Oh you were right! I think it was a bug, restarted xCode an rearranged it and bam - it worked! Thank you so much!